# Error while starting virtual device using Virtual box and Genymotion

Tags: android, virtualbox, genymotion

I am trying to start the virtual device from virtualbox and run the emulator from genymotion.

I tried this: Virtual Box "Settings" > System Settings > Processor > Enable the PAE/NX option but did not work for me

here is the screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

While genymotion relies on virtualbox, you don't need to mess with virtualbox to use genymotion. Start the virtual machine from within genymotion.

Comment: I tried this but this cannot be done. It displays me error that virtual box start is required from virtualbox